# Combine several missing index suggestions with one index?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index, index-tuning

I investigate on missing indexes recommendations of my sql server engine.

Looking at the most useful ones (for a specific table) that are candidates based on their potential usage and potential improvement impact, I wonder if some of the candidates left might be covered by just one index (or at least by less indices than sql server suggests to create).

Samles:

```
 1. EQUALITY: [OID], [DFlag] INEQUALITY: [Stat]
 2. EQUALITY: [OID], [DFlag], [ChangeNr] INEQUALITY: [UID] INCLUDES: [Stat]  
 3. EQUALITY: [OID], [DFlag], [ChangeNr] INEQUALITY: [UID] INCLUDES: [ID], [Int], [Stat]
```

So I wonder if maybe index No.1 might already be covered by index no. 2 because the search predicates are also included there?
And if index no. 2 might be covered by creation of index no. 3 because it hase the same predicates and the included colum is part of the included columns there as well?

So my thesis is that by creation of index 3 the missing index suggestions of no 1 + 2 in theory should dissapear because index no. 3 could perfectly meet the criteria of all of those. It this correct?

Comment: Sounds about right, yes. Just make sure that you have enough queries that benefit from index 3 to justify the overhead, since it will take more space. Same with index 2. The problem with a lot of recommendations is that they're based on *single executions* of queries, and no broader view of the entire system. If the index benefits a query that you run once a month, it may not be worth having.

Comment: Also if you look at index 1 you are actually indexing the Stat column.  In 2 and 3 the Stat column is in the include section.  It may not matter depending on how unique OID & DFlag are but it might.

Comment: I don't get what "INEQUALITY" stands for in the suggestion. Is the column to be in the main part of the index or in the `INCLUDE` part?

Comment: Inequality means that it is used with a not equal (like <>) filter in the queries. it is recommended to add those columns after the equality columns as part of the index. Watch this: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/08/mysteries-missing-indexes-video/

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, since those condidates are the ones remaining after I filtered away all those recommendations not being used a lot or not having much impact, I would guess that all of them are very useful. Whan say "enough queries" you mean enough query executions, right?

Comment: All you said was "most useful ones" - that is very vague and I still have no idea how exactly you filtered the others out. And yes, I mean both different queries and multiple executions of the same query.